# What is the general solution of $2xydx + (x^2 + 2y)dy = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to check to see if the given $x^2y + y^2 = C$ is a general solution of the differential equation below:

$$
2xydx + (x^2 + 2y)dy = 0
$$

I eventually solved for $C$ and came to this conclusion:

$$
C=2y^3/(2y+4)
$$

Am I correct in saying that the given $x^2y + y^2 = C$ is a general solution of the differential equation if $C$ is equal to what I solved for above? Or is it possible to get a non-variable value for $C$? Note: The differential equation is not subject to an initial condition.

Comment: what did you do to get $ 2y^3/(2y+4)?$

Comment: @abel First I solved for $dx$ and $dy$ seperately. $dx=2xy$ and $dy=2y+x^2$. I plugged this into the differential equation and combined like terms. This resulted in $2x^2y^2+4x^2y+4y^2=0$. I then took the given equation $x^2y+y^2=C$ and solved for $x$. This resulted in $x=sqroot((C-y^2)/y)$. I then plugged this into the differential equation and solved for $C$.

Comment: what does it mean to say $dx = 2xy?$ every term in an expression needs an infinitesimal. like $2xy\, dx + (x^2 + 2y)\, dy = 0$

Comment: the general solution of $2xy\, dx + (x^2+y) \, dy = 0$  is $x^2y + y^2 = C$  where $C$ is a constant. there is nothing more need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let
$$
f(x,y)=2xy \qquad g(x,y)=x^2+2y 
$$
and you have 
$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)= 2x
$$
so this is an exact equation.

Search $F(x,y)$ such that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,y)=2xy$ and
$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}F(x,y)=x^2+y$ and the solution is $F(x,y)=C$.

> $F(x,y)=x^2y+y^2=C$.

Comment: Why did you find $del/dely$ of $f(x,y)$ and not $del/delx$? How did you determine which partial derivative to use for $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$?

Comment: I'm searching for $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}=\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x}$. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential#Two_and_three_dimensions